# What is the standard way to secure a REST API using Tokens?

Tags: node.js, rest, security, oauth

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have server that serves data using a REST API, but I want only my mobile clients(an APP) to access this.

I would like to use a similar system where a user can create a Email/Password log in. After that, the user can access certain data using the API.

Is OAuth2 the right thing to use?

Or do I just try to create my own protocol and generate a token for the user. And have the user attach a token on all API requests.  (This is where I'm confused.  Can I use OAuth for that? or is that even needed?  If not is there a standard HTTP way to do this? Also I would like to use refresh tokens, but I'm not sure If i should create my own methods.

Comment: Did you have a look at [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/)?

Comment: If any of the answers provided was helpful/right please accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 would probably be the best and most widely used solution. I'd go with that.

Implementing your own authentication/authorization protocols almost always ends in disaster, unless you have a very deep understanding in cryptography and the underlying protocols.

Comment: I've looked at OAuth, I thought it is used to use a 3rd party (Facebook) and have them authenticate the user.  In my case, I don't have any 3rd party authenticator.  Do i do some kind of loop back and pretend I'm a 3rd party and issue authentication that way?  Or is that how everyone does it?

Comment: Your API acts as the OAuth2 server. The server grants an access token after the users email/password credentials have been verified. You can see a visualization of the flow here: http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2/grants/password.html

Answer (score 0):

Mind the fact that OAuth is not an *authentication* protocol - which seems is what you need - but a *authorization* protocol. You server is a client that requests the resources that OAuth provider has - is that what you need? I guess no.

What you rather need is an authentication protocol - which typically works by sending some token with every request - and mentioned by @Julian [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) seems to be doing the job you need.

Basically stay away from implementing custom solutions. You really need a wide knowledge to implement reliable and secure authentication scheme.

JSON web token might be the way to go as well.

Comment: I thought OAuth still do authentication by having user enter their username/password at the authentication server, the authentication server then grants access to the user and the resource server.  The resource server then gives authorization to the user. Using a token.  What I'm confused about is is there a strict set of calls/protocols/http header to make in order to be OAuth compliant?

Comment: @mskw, I'm against using OAuth for securing REST API, because that's not for what OAuth was invented. But it doesn't mean it can't be used, the scenario you provided in a comment is perfectly valid. Yes, there's is a strict set, OAuth is standarized.

Answer (score 0):

If client applications are developed only by you, you don't need OAuth. OAuth is needed only when you want to allow third-party client applications to access (your service's) users' data with restricted privileges.

Related questions:

1. [Understanding the need of client id, client secret in oauth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34312799/1174054)
2. [How to verify which resources each user can access with OAuth and OpenID Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34377012/1174054)
3. [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server and Access Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34371782/1174054)

However, if there is a possibility that you may want to allow third-party client applications to access your system in the future, it may be wise to implement [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3), which is one of [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) flows, from the beginning for the future extensibility.

Comment: I wanted to use a standard way to secure my API, so I thought the way OAuth issued tokens were the way to go.  How does other apps do it typically if only my app is trying to access my API?